# No Slather Cobertura XML Outputs

Tags: jenkins, cobertura, slather

I am currently configuring a Jenkins job to run a suite of unit tests for an iOS project and publish code coverage results with Cobertura. I am using Slather to generate the .xml coverage report for Cobertura. The problem I am running into is that the slather coverage does not appear to actually be outputting anything to the listed *--output-directory*.

**Jenkins Execute Shell:**

```
/usr/local/bin/slather coverage \
--cobertura-xml -x --output-directory ${WORKSPACE}/MyProject/test-reports/coveragereport \
--source-files MyProject/WebServices \
--verbose \
-s \
--scheme MyProjectTests \
--binary-file MyProject/artifacts/MyProject.app/MyProject \
MyProject/MyProject.xcodeproj
```

I have tried a couple different variations of the syntax for the output:

- --cobertura-xml ${WORKSPACE}/MyProject/test-reports/coveragereport
- -x --output-directory ${WORKSPACE}/MyProject/test-reports/coveragereport

I have tried these with various output directories with and without using the workspace variable in case it was having trouble with the default root.

**Jenkins Console:**

```
Test Coverage: 26.72%
Slathered
Recording test results
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...
[Cobertura] No coverage results were found using the pattern 'MyProject/test-reports/coveragereport/*.xml' relative to '/Users/jenkins/workspace/iOS/myproject/Unit_Tests'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the XML report(s) for Cobertura?
Build step 'Publish Cobertura Coverage Report' changed build result to FAILURE
```

We can see that the slather coverage is working indicated by the test coverage result, however Cobertura cannot find the report. This is of course because the **.xml** it is looking for is not being generated/output.

**TLDR:**

Any idea what I can do to guarantee the **.xml** report that Cobertura is looking for is actually generated/output?

Comment: I had the same issue. The issue is with the --output-directory. You shouldn't specify the absolute path. Just specify the relative path of .xml file generated in workspace

Comment: The output xml file has to be in the same folder as where coverage is run